# public var of an Objective C enum type inside a Swift class not accessible from another Objective C class

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have an enum defined in Enums.h -

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ScreenTypes)
{
    ScreenA = 0,
    ScreenB,
    ScreenC,
    ScreenD
};
```

Next, I declare a public var of this enum in a Swift class XYZ.swift

```
public var screenType: ScreenTypes?
```

However, when I am trying to access screenType from an Objective C view controller class, it gives compile error -  Property 'screenType' not found on object of type 'XYZ *'

Please help!!

Comment: Is `Enums.h ` included in your `~Bridging-Header.h` ?

Comment: Yes, I have included it.

Comment: Optional enums or structs are not available in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.